# Rendering a chart-js line chart after a promise has returned data

Tags: angularjs, charts

The user goes to their dashboard page and I have a factory returning data for that page. When the promise returns the tables update OK, but chart-js doesn't render.

If I mock up some data and put it *outside* of my `.then()` code the chart will render on the page, but move it inside and it doesn't.

I believe the problem is something to do with this bit of code running "too early". It looks for lineOptions and lineData before they've come back.

```
<canvas linechart=""
    options="lineOptions"
    data="lineData"
    height="260"
    responsive="false"
    width="1200"></canvas>
```

I'm new-ish to Angular and I'm not entirely sure how to go about solving this chicken and egg problem.

How can I tell `<canvas>` to wait until lineData and lineOptions are populated?

I've tried ng-show/ng-hide calling a function to check for data and this doesn't work. I've also tried ng-if also to no effect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how it looks in your code. But did you try to do something like this?

```
var chartInstance = new Chart(canvasContext);

// then for your promise object:    
{"some deferred object that retrieves the data"}.then(function(data) {
    chartInstance.Line(data);
});
```

Reference to the docs: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-creating-a-chart

Comment: That's the one. Thank you! ... Turns out I didn't know you could call `.Line` on the chartInstance like that.